# Twitter API JSON to jQuery check if key exists

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I can successfully get a tweet from the Twitter API. Beside the user, the tweet and some other data I display the image as well, but when there is no image attached to the tweet, nothing is displayed as the key does not exist.

```
    $.getJSON('gettweet.php', function(tweet){

    $("#mention_tweet").append("<p class='tweet' id='tweet'>" + tweet.text + "</p>" +
                        "<a href='" + tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https + "' /></a>")

});
```

This is working as far as `tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https` exists.
How can I check this?

I tried these, with no success:

```
if (tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https != 'undefined')
if (tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https != null)
if (tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https.length > 0)
if (entities.media[0].media_url_https in tweet) 
if (typeof tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https !== 'undefined')
if (!empty(tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('gettweet.php', function(tweet){
    var content = '';
    if (tweet.entities.media && tweet.entities.media.length > 0 && tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https)
    {
        content = "<p class='tweet' id='tweet'>" + tweet.text + "</p>" +
                  "<a href='" + tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https + 
                  "' target='_blank'><img src='" + 
                  tweet.entities.media[0].media_url_https + "' /></a>";
    } else {
        content = "<p class='tweet' id='tweet'>" + tweet.text + "</p>";
    }
    $("#mention_tweet").append(content);
});
```

Comment: It's not that easy. Tried this as well, just left it out.

Comment: When I specifically test the json it works for me. After `json_encode($string);` I can call `if ($string['entities']['media'][0]['media_url_https'])`. Things seem to be different when I run the script from jquery.

Comment: Tried your code. When there is no image attached, nothing happens. With an image, both the tweet and the image is shown.

Comment: ARE THERE ANY ERRORS IN YOUR JAVASCRIPT CONSOLE?

Comment: Try my updated code.  You need to check if the media array is defined and not empty before trying to access an element in it.

Comment: Found that out after reading the error message thoroughly. Thank you!